# Adding information to point when created with PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

How do I add information to a point when I'm creating it with Python in QGIS. I want to add some info to the point like `id`, `name`, etc...

This is my code:

```
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326', 'point' , 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()
point = QgsPoint(point)
feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))
prov.addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([layer])
```

Comment: Which version of QGIS do you use?

Comment: You need to add fields to your new table using something like:prov.addAttributes(
        [QgsField("MapNo", QVariant.Double)]) and then feat.setAttributes([counter]) to add a value to the attribute table before adding your feature

Answer (score 5):

**For QGIS 3.x**, you can use the script below:

```
# Create layer with some fields
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer&field=name:string', 'point' , 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()

# new feature
feat = QgsFeature()

# set fields
feat.setFields(layer.fields())

# set geometry
point = QgsPointXY(1, 2)
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(point))

# set value for specific field
feat["id"] = 0
feat["name"] = "a name"

# add 'feat' to the layer
prov.addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()

# add 'layer' to the project
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
```

**For QGIS 2.18+**: Notice the highlighted lines (`######`). They are different from QGIS 3.x

```
# Create layer with some fields
layer = QgsVectorLayer('Point?crs=epsg:4326&field=id:integer&field=name:string', 'point' , 'memory')
prov = layer.dataProvider()

# new feature
feat = QgsFeature()

# set fields
feat.setFields(layer.fields())

# set geometry
point = QgsPoint(1, 2)  ######
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(point))  ######

# set value for specific field
feat["id"] = 0
feat["name"] = "a name"

# add 'feat' to the layer
prov.addFeatures([feat])
layer.updateExtents()

# add 'layer' to the project
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer) ######.
```